# Webpack Dev Server, allow paths with `dot` in them

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

In my React.js app I have a route like this:

```
/foo/foo.bar/foo
```

When I load this URL (clicking *refresh* on the browser), I get:

```
Cannot GET /foo/foo.bar/foo
```

I think the problem is that Webpack Dev Server thinks that this URL refers to a static asset and tries to load it.

How can I fix this problem? (I need the dot)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need to set up a proxy, you can simply tell Webpack (*or more specifically the [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback#disabledotrule) that it uses*) not to treat paths with dots in them as static assets by setting [`disableDotRule`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) to `true` in your Webpack configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Did the job! Excellent!

Comment: Good to hear :)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer because I didn't recognize that you were using webpack dev server:**
You can make a proxy in webpack.config.js that forwards requests made to /foo/foo.bar. You can either forward the requests to another backend server that serves your index.html file, or you can override the proxy and have it return index.html directly. Example configuration below

```
proxy: [
    {
        path: /\/foo\/foo.bar\/foo/,
        bypass: function(req, res, proxyOptions) {
            return '/index.html';
        }
    }
]
```

It's a bit hacky, but it works.

Comment: @FezVrasta oh. sorry. Are you not using any other backend at all? If you are you could just proxy the request. If not you can probably bypass the proxy to return index.html (see https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#bypass-the-proxy)

Comment: No, I'm just using webpack dev server